# What is the simplest way to set the focus order in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a column of TextFields, something like:

```kotlin
Column {
    TextField(
        value = ...,
        onValueChange = { ... },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.next),
    )
    TextField(
        value = ...,
        onValueChange = { ... },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.next),
    )
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I would like to have the focus on each TextField move to the next when the user press Tab, or the next button on the keyboard. Currently pressing Tab inserts a tab into the TextField. Pressing the next button does nothing. I can create a FocusRequester for each TextField and set the keyboardActions onNext to request focus on the next field for each one. This is a little tedious and it doesn't address the Tab behavior.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I recently found this article: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/focus-in-jetpack-compose-6584252257fe

It explains a different way to handle focus that is quite a bit simpler.

```kotlin
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .onPreviewKeyEvent {
            if (it.key == Key.Tab && it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN){
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { it -> text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
    )
)
```

Comment: Just a couple of things to add to this: instead of `it.key.keyCode == Key.Tab.keyCode` you can simply do `it.key == Key.Tab`, however if you want to avoid the experimental API opt-in you can instead do `it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB`. Also, it's better to use `Modifier.onPreviewKeyEvent`since `Modifier.onKeyEvent` calls `onValueChange` *before* propagating the key event, so you could end up in situations where the TextField you just tabbed out of now has an extra tab character that the user isn't aware of.

Comment: I'm finding that adding this invokes the onPreviewKeyEvent action twice so it move focus twice – any clue why?

Comment: oh, its because there's both a key down and key up event

Comment: for me looks like `keyboardActions` is not needed

Comment: This works perfectly if you just need to "re-emit" onNext event in case you handle something there already. (If you listen to onNext it ignores it, this way you can restore default behaviour)

Comment: They `keyboardActions` is to change the behavior with a soft keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if it's the easier way, but you can create a `FocusRequester` object for each field and request the focus following the order that you want.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FocusRequestScreen() {
    // Create FocusRequesters... (you can use createRefs function)
    val focusRequesters = List(3) { FocusRequester() }

    Column {
        TextFieldWithFocusRequesters(focusRequesters[0], focusRequesters[1])
        TextFieldWithFocusRequesters(focusRequesters[1], focusRequesters[2])
        TextFieldWithFocusRequesters(focusRequesters[2], focusRequesters[0])
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TextFieldWithFocusRequesters(
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
    nextFocusRequester: FocusRequester
) {
    var state by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("Focus Transition Test")
    }
    TextField(
        value = state,
        onValueChange = { text -> state = text },
        // Here it is what you want...
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusOrder(focusRequester) {
                nextFocusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        ,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next)
    )
}
```

I get this code from [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1520028/6/compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/text/ComposeInputFieldFocusTransition.kt). It didn't solve the tab issue though... :(

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not shift the screen up in case the focused `TextField` is covered by the keyboard... any clue how to achieve that?

Comment: The solution proposed by Gary Wang seems a lot cleaner as it doesn't require you to create a list of `FocusRequester` nor wrap the `TextField` in a new composable.

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently on `compose_version = '1.0.2'`.

Focus is not moved when you press the next button because, although [the default keyboard action is to move focus to the next one](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/25194228b009c015206cb3d24008f7eced7843ad/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardActionRunner.kt#L67), compose seems doesn't know which one should be the next one. Creating `FocusRequester` s for each item and set their focus order via `Modifier.focusOrder() {}` could work (btw, no need to set the `keyboardActions`'s `onNext` to request focus if you are choosing this way), but since your `TextField`s are in the same `Column`, you can just set `keyboardActions` to tell compose move the focus to the one in the down direction. Something like:

```kotlin
        Column {
            val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
            TextField(
                value = "", onValueChange = {},
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( imeAction = ImeAction.Next ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
                )
            )
            TextField(
                value = "", onValueChange = {},
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( imeAction = ImeAction.Next ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
                )
            )
            TextField(
                value = "", onValueChange = {},
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( imeAction = ImeAction.Next ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
                )
            )
        }
```

After you did this, the next button on the IME keyboard should works.

For the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, since `TextField` doesn't deal with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key automately, so you might want to use `focusManager` inside `Modifier.onKeyEvent{}` to move focus in the same way as the above example did.

Answer (score 5):

About the order you can check the [@nglauber answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66819665/2016562).

To use the Tab key you can use the [**`onKeyEvent`** modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/key/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onKeyEvent(kotlin.Function1)).

```
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onKeyEvent {
            if (it.key.keyCode == Key.Tab.keyCode){
                focusRequesterNext.requestFocus()
                true //true -> consumed
            } else false },
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { it -> text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = {focusRequesterNext.requestFocus()}
        )
)
```

Comment: Just a couple of things to add to this: instead of `it.key.keyCode == Key.Tab.keyCode` you can simply do `it.key == Key.Tab`, however if you want to avoid the experimental API opt-in you can instead do `it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB`. Also, it's better to use `Modifier.onPreviewKeyEvent`since `Modifier.onKeyEvent` calls `onValueChange` *before* propagating the key event, so you could end up in situations where the TextField you just tabbed out of now has an extra tab character that the user isn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Set singleLine , please try

```
OutlinedTextField(
...
singleLine = true,
)
```

Simple example

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var text1 by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var text2 by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column() {
        OutlinedTextField(value = text1, onValueChange = {
            text1 = it
        },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onNext ={
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                }
            ),
            singleLine = true
            )
        OutlinedTextField(value = text2, onValueChange = {
            text2 = it
        },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onNext ={
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                }
            ),
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Google has a recommended approach here that hasn't been suggested yet - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/focus/change-focus-traversal-order

```kotlin
val (first, second, third, fourth) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }
```

```kotlin
Column {
    Row {
        TextButton(
            {},
            Modifier
                .focusRequester(first)
                .focusProperties { next = second }
        ) {
            Text("First field")
        }
        TextButton(
            {},
            Modifier
                .focusRequester(third)
                .focusProperties { next = fourth }
        ) {
            Text("Third field")
        }
    }

    Row {
        TextButton(
            {},
            Modifier
                .focusRequester(second)
                .focusProperties { next = third }
        ) {
            Text("Second field")
        }
        TextButton(
            {},
            Modifier
                .focusRequester(fourth)
                .focusProperties { next = first }
        ) {
            Text("Fourth field")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's good to see google's recommendation. This is basically the solution proposed by nglauber. `Modifier.focusOrder` has been deprecated in favor of `Modifier.focusProperties` and `FocusRequester.createRefs` is an experimental convenience method to create the focus requesters.