# why does not focusManager work in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, focusmanager

I am trying move focus from user textfield to password textfield with imeAction onNext and focusDirection.down, but the focus is cleared when I press the next button of the keyboard.
[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIB8B.png)

I show the code here:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
//we start to implement login screen UI-->
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        item {
            
        item {
            OutlinedTextField(

                value = emailValue.value,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
                ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onNext ={
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                    }

                ),
```

Comment: Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817856/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-set-the-focus-order-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 0):

Set singleLine , please try

```
OutlinedTextField(
...
singleLine = true,
)
```

simple example

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var text1 by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LazyColumn() {
        items(2){
            OutlinedTextField(value = text1, onValueChange = {
                text1 = it
            },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
                ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onNext ={
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                    }
                ),
                singleLine = true
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: singleLine is enabled in my code, but it does´nt work

Comment: I don't know why, I added two outlinedTextFields in Column, which was effective.@agmcoder

Comment: I added my sample code @agmcoder